# Spock stub does not return expected value

Tags: unit-testing, groovy, spock

I'm trying to use a Spock Stub to mock a database/repository dependency in my service class, but I'm having an issue with the stub returning an unexpected value. I don't understand why the stub only works when I don't pass an argument to the mocked method.

```
given: 'I have client data'
Client client = new Client("Foo", "bar@baz.org")

and: 'a client repository always returns the id'
clientRepository = Stub(ClientRepository)
ClientEntity ce = new ClientEntity("Foo", "bar@baz.org")
clientRepository.create(ce) >> 1

when: 'I add the client'
ClientService clientService = new ClientServiceImpl(clientRepository)
Client addedClient = clientService.addClient(client)

then: 'The client object should be populated correctly'
addedClient.getId() == 1 // This fails b/c it's returning the id as 0
```

But when I use the _ argument the test passes:

```
given: 'I have client data'
Client client = new Client("Foo", "bar@baz.org")

and: 'a client repository always returns the id'
clientRepository = Stub(ClientRepository)
clientRepository.create(_) >> 1

when: 'I add the client'
ClientService clientService = new ClientServiceImpl(clientRepository)
Client addedClient = clientService.addClient(client)

then: 'The client object should be populated correctly'
addedClient.getId() == 1 // This passes b/c it's returning the id as 1
```

Here are the Service class

```
@Service
public class ClientServiceImpl implements ClientService{

    private ClientRepository clientRepository;

    @Autowired
    ClientServiceImpl(ClientRepository clientRepository){
        this.clientRepository = clientRepository;
    }

    @Override
    public Client addClient(Client client){

        ClientEntity clientEntity = new ClientEntity(
                client.getName(),
                client.getEmailAddress()
        );

        int id = clientRepository.create(clientEntity);
        client.setId(id);

        return client;
    }
}
```

And the Spock dependency

```
 <dependency>
            <groupId>org.spockframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spock-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.3-groovy-2.5</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.spockframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spock-spring</artifactId>
            <version>1.3-groovy-2.5</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do this

```
ClientEntity ce = new ClientEntity("Foo", "bar@baz.org")
clientRepository.create(ce) >> 1
```

and the stubbed interaction is not being executed, then because the method argument was not matched according to your expectation. My guess is that the `equals(..)` method of `ClientEntity` does not work as you expect it to and that the argument given to `create(..)` is not exactly `ce` but a copy of it which does not satisfy `equals(..)`.

Solution: Fix your `equals(..)` method.

Comment: I overrode the equals method in `ClientEntity` but it didn't solve the issue

Comment: Changed the implementation of the equals() and it worked.